# Which version of SSMS corresponds to Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, ssms

Does SSMS borrow components from visual studio?  If so, how do you know what versions it borrows from?

If you install corresponding versions (using shared components), then it stands to reason that they will have a smaller overall footprint.

Comment: It shouldn't matter what version of SSMS you are using. Visual studio only cares about the database, SSMS and visual studio don't really work together the way you are describing. I am using SSMS 2017 with visual studio 2017 and sql server 2016

Answer (score 0):

None, as of today.

[SSMS 17.X is based on the Visual Studio 2015 Isolated shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15#supported-operating-systems)

Comment: Enough resources have been moved to the open source/cross platform SQL Operation Studio, https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2018/07/19/the-july-release-of-sql-operations-studio-is-now-available/ So I wonder if there is any need to keep SSMS in the near future.